# Printing from Chrome on Zebra ZD421

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing, zebra-printers

I need to print both a web page and a PDF from within Chrome to a Zebra ZD421. However, despite experimenting with the Rotation setting in the driver, it insists on printing the label in landscape orientation (using up half of the label). There is no orientation setting in the Chrome print dialog, so I'm kinda stumped.

Comment: OK. Hands up. User error. It was simply incorrect label size set in the driver. With the correct dimensions set, the orientation is as expected!

Answer (score 0):

Orientation is usually set in the driver manually so surprised its rejected.

The best I can do is show this web page printed from Edge(Chromium)

Is not a problem using the current Zebra Drivers. Rotation is set in Edge leaving the default as portrait unrotated which is the web in landscape :-)
Then in driver did a second portrait rotated which is the lower portrait image.

[image]

This may seem quirky but is sometimes the case where the expectations as to page rotation differs. Here you can see in two label drivers (the second is model spefic where I am printing from Portrait PDF) that the portrait graphic is shown as if using landscape format labels, and Landscape appears as if its portrait, the term is nominal based on printer direction.

[image]
[image]